# Database design for employee availability

Tags: database-design, scheduling

I am trying to design a system, where employees would declare their availability and I would then be able to search through this data and find if there’s any conflict.

The employees can set their general availability like this: I am available from May 1st to July 22th from 10:00 to 16:00.

Then they can set exceptions such as: I am unavailable from May 5th to May 7th from 14:00 to 16:00.

I was thinking about converting these declarations into specific 10 minute time slots creating record for every day and every time and then deleting slots declared as unavailable. But I’m not sure how to keep the data consistent.

What is an efficient way to store and query this data?

Comment: The easiest way to store the general and exception data would be start date, end date, start time, and end time.  Your application would figure out the 10-minute slots for a particular week or pay period, as needed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how would I query the data from such table? I’m not sure how would I make it efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an existing `Employee` table with an `EmployeeID` defined, you would create two tables, `GeneralAvailability` and `Exemption`.

```
GeneralAvailability
-------------------
GeneralAvailabilityID
EmployeeID
StartDate
EndDate
StartTime
EndTime
```

Where `GeneralAvailabilityID` is an incrementing integer default primary key.  You would also create an index on (EmployeID, StartDate desc).

You would query this table with a `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT *
    FROM GeneralAvailability
    WHERE EmployeeID = 'some id'
    AND StartDate <= current date
    ORDER BY EmployeeID, StartDate desc
```

Now, you'll probably retrieve multiple rows. The first row is the most recent general availability row with the dates and times.

I used a `SELECT *` for typing convenience.  In your code, you would specify all of the columns you want to retrieve by name.

The `Exemption` table would have an identical structure and a slightly different query.  Your application would process the multiple exemptions for an employee.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Exemption
    WHERE EmployeeID = 'some id'
    AND StartDate >= current date
    ORDER BY EmployeeID, StartDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the query example but how would I check for availability in one query? Do I need to get the GeneralAvailability first and then check against Exemptions? I thought that this should be a single query.

Comment: @wyktor: Nope.  Two separate queries returning two separate sets of information.